# Restricting the domain of the trigonometric functions in identities

Tags: trigonometry

I have this formula in my textbook:

$
\sin ^2 \alpha =  \frac{\tan ^2 \alpha}{1+\tan^2 \alpha}
$
where $\alpha \neq \frac{\pi}{2}+ k\pi $

I think that the restriction for the angle is wrong and it should be $\alpha \neq k \times \frac{\pi}{2}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Also i want some advice on how to take care of the angle restriction when moving from one formula to another. For example in some formula we restrict the angle and then do some algebraic transformations and get a new formula with different trigonometric function etc. How to connect the previous angle restrictions to the current ones that arise in the new formula? I guess this is general for all functions and so for the trigonometric but let's hear your opinion.

Comment: The restriction in the textbook is correct. It excludes values of $\alpha$ for which $\tan\alpha$ is not finite, so it avoids having the indeterminate expression $\infty/\infty$ on the right hand side. Remember, the period of the tangent function is $\pi$, and its graph has a vertical asymptote at odd multiples of $\pi/2$.

Comment: My restriction of the angle doesn't allow the angle to be on the y axis because there the tangent is undefined. It also doesn't allow the angle to be on the x axis because there the sine function is zero and here we must restrict the sine to not be equal to zero. This is ommited in the textbook's restriction. Am i missing something?

Comment: Why are you not allowing the sine to be zero? There's nothing wrong with allowing it to be zero. The left side of the equation is $0$, the right side is $\frac{0}{1+0^2} = 0$. You are excluding values that don't need to be excluded.

Comment: But if we rewrite the equation with the $\sin^2\alpha$ in the denominator on the RHS then it must not be zero?

Comment: Isn't it added to $1$ in the denominator, not just by itself? That's okay, right? $1/(1+0)$ is just $1$.

Comment: If we have $1+\tan^2\alpha$ on the LHS and $\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}$ on the RHS than the sine must not be zero.

Comment: That's true, but you didn't mention that in the question. Also, if you are only using such division in an intermediate step, and it doesn't appear in the final result, you can still manually verify that the formula is correct for those values of $\alpha$ even if they are excluded during the derivation.

Comment: So you want to say that if we excluded some value for $\alpha$ in some step in the derivation of the final formula, then it is possible the final formula to be defined for that value for $\alpha$? How/Why is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RHS is undefined when the tangent is infinite, i.e. when the cosine is $0$. This occurs for $-\frac\pi2$, $\frac\pi2$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}2$... i.e. $(k+\frac12)\pi$.

Anyway we have
$$\lim_{\alpha\to(k+\frac12)\pi}\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=1=\lim_{\alpha\to(k+\frac12)\pi}\sin^2\alpha,$$
so that the formula is virtually valid everywhere.

The rules for angle restrictions follow from the rules of equation manipulation:

- the domain must exclude the values for which expressions are undefined,
- it must also exclude the values for which the equation transformation rules are violated.

Example: you may not divide by zero. So a transform like $\sin^4\alpha=\sin^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha\implies\sin^2\alpha=1-\cos^2\alpha$ must exclude $\alpha=k\pi$.

Once a value has been excluded, it remains excluded for the rest of the derivation. (But you are allowed to treat special cases separately.)